# Redirect page after session time out using api controller in MVC

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, session, controller, session-timeout

I am using Controller and ApiController both in my mvc single page application .I am using session timeout from web config.I an able to redirect from controller but not from apiController.

Is redirect url possible from apiController after checking session variable?

If yes,then please provide me help on this implementation.

Thanks in Advance.
Kamini

Answer (score 1):

I know its old but maybe it can help someone...
You should intercept the response in your client and reload the page when HTTP status == 401.
here is an angular example that intercept all application http responses:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
          return {
              'response': function(response)
              {
                  if (response.status === 401)
                      location.reload();
                  return response;
              }
          }
      });

  }])
```